# Prevent X/Gnome/Terminal from catching emacs commands

Tags: shortcut-keys, emacs

When I use `emacs`, I often end up typing many exciting key combinations which I would usually not use, such as <kbd>C-M-t</kbd> (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>Alt</kbd> - <kbd>T</kbd>), which in emacs is supposed to run the command `transpose-sexps`; however, since X or Gnome (I'm not sure which) is catching this event, this has the actual effect of opening a Terminal. Nevertheless, I enjoy and am used to having the functionality to open a new Terminal—provided that I don't have emacs open. So, is there any way to temporarily disable all keyboard shortcuts whenever the current focus is on emacs?

N.B. I happen to be using the non-graphical version of emacs `emacs-nox`, so I in fact usually have a Terminal running `emacs`, not a graphical emacs window.

Comment: Relevant, but unanswered: http://askubuntu.com/questions/532031/how-exactly-do-global-shortkeys-work

Comment: i would very much like to know the answer to this. It's been 5 years and currently on 16.04 the only way to use emacs is to laboriously go through keyboard settings and disable every shortcut key with Ctrl and / or Alt, not to mention there are some emacs commands that are bound to Super (Windows/Mac) keys. If only there were a way to disable all shortcut keys when in Emacs, that would solve the problem instantly.